# perl multiple line replace of variable length method

Tags: regex, perl

Can you please provide a perl script or command that will remove the following code from a file?  In some cases, there may be a space between the '-' and (void).  I have tried many variations and have not gotten it to work.  Thank you!

```
-(void)dealloc {
    ... could be multiple lines here    
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Here are several things I tried:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/- (void)dealloc.*\s*.*super dealloc];.*\n}//g' File.txt
perl -i -0pe 's/^'- (void)dealloc'.*\n.*[super dealloc];\n}$//' File.txt
perl -i -0pe 's/^-[ ](void)dealloc.*\n.*[super dealloc];\n}$//' File.txt
perl -i -0pe 's/^-\s(void)dealloc.*\n.*\\'[super dealloc]\';\n}$//' File.txt
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Thanks in advance.  I updated the question with several things I have tried so far.

Comment: `*` in a regex usually means zero-or-more — since the space is optional, don't you need a `*` in your regex?  Or use `?` if it must be zero-or-one instead of zero-or-more.

Comment: Thanks, Effort in the question leads to effort in the answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `(`, `)`, `[` and `]`, `{` and `}` have special meanings in regex patterns. If you want to match these characters, you will need to escape them in the pattern.
- You required the space between `-` and `(void)` even though you indicated it should be optional.
- You only match one line where you say you want to match multiple lines.
- `-0777` is actually slurp mode, not `-0`.
- I don't get those quotes?!?!

So,

```
perl -i -0777pe's/^-[ ]?\(void\)dealloc.*?\[super dealloc\];\s*\}\n//msg' file
```

- `/m` makes `^` match at the start of a line rather than (just) at the start of the string.
- `/s` allows `.` to match newlines.
- `?` or `[ ]?` optionally matches a space. (The latter is a little easier to read.)
- `.*?` matches the least possible at that position.

Comment: Thank you very much ikegami!  This works like a charm and is extremely helpful.  I appreciate it more than you know!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to provide a full-fledged solution to your problem, but I'd like to point to a technique that might be helpful in contexts like these.

It's based on a not very known behaviour of the `..` operator in Perl. In scalar context it acts as a bi-stable boolean operator. Let me quote [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> In scalar context, ".." returns a boolean value. The operator is
>   bistable, like a flip-flop, and emulates the line-range (comma)
>   operator of sed, awk, and various editors. Each ".." operator
>   maintains its own boolean state, even across calls to a subroutine
>   that contains it. It is false as long as its left operand is false.
>   Once the left operand is true, the range operator stays true until the
>   right operand is true, AFTER which the range operator becomes false
>   again.

This means you could write the solution in a more expressive way, like:

```
if ( /-[ ]?\(void\)dealloc/ .. /^\}/ ) {
  ... this code is executed when you enter the block ...
}
```

The advantage IMO is that you do not have to deal directly with the inner block, and your intention is more evident to someone that reads the code. I hope this helps.

Comment: In other words, the OP could use `perl -ne'print if !(/-[ ]?\(void\)dealloc/ .. /^}/);'`, EXCEPT that wouldn't check for `[super dealloc];`.

Comment: Yes. I should've said, at the beginning of my answer, that I felt like mentioning a technique useful in *similar* contexts

Comment: Cut the sarcasm. My comment wasn't a critique; it actually addressed two issues with your question: You didn't show how it could be used, and you didn't explain what the issue made it hard for the OP to take advantage of your "solution". But if you want a critique, here's one: If you want to post a Q&A, do that; don't hijack someone else's question. Then, people could actually link to it!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  I used the solution below, but I appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: @ikegami No sarcasm implied, really. You're right my answer could have stated that it didn't address one of the requirements. Believe it or not, it was a attempt to provide hints useful to the OP. I didn't know I breaked some rule or policy here.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were pointing out that you did. ("I'm not going to provide a full-fledged solution to your problem")

Comment: @ikegami ok. Albeit unnecessarily harsh (at least, that's the way I read your comments) I appreciate your suggestions and I'll act accordingly in the future